# How Can I add javascript for separate div's?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I give javascript for every div instead of the whole page?

```
<head>
    my jquery
    my javascript for the whole page
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cc1">
    Some content - I want to add Javascript for this div
    </div>
</body>
```

I know we add javascript only in head of the page or we call functions write in external js in onclick of html button events.

I need separate JS for each div because I am going to have a `<noscript>` in every div to show some static ad content if user has disabled  javascript ; else if user has already enabled javascript, I am going to generate a dynamic  ad content with my own javascript.

So how you do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "add javascript for every DIV"? What do you want to do with the DIVs ?

Comment: Agreed, are you generating these pages dynamically?  Also, although the best practice is to only add javascript in the `head` element, there are cases in which doing so is not always the best idea (i.e. when you want the javascript to be able to reference DOM elements _after_ they have been created)

Comment: so there is a possibility? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to do something like this:

```
<div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Content A");
  </script>
  <noscript>
      Alternate content
  </noscript>
</div>

<div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write("Content B");
  </script>
  <noscript>
      Alternate content
  </noscript>
</div>
```

This is an old-fashioned way of doing things and I don't recommend it.  An alternative to using inline script/noscript tags is to put the "noscript" content in the divs, then replace the content with JavaScript after the page loads; that way, if JavaScript is disabled, the original content will remain.

Comment: Both ideas are okay for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly, you cannot really add JavaScript for a div, you should add it for the whole page and then use it just in that div.

To make something happen inside that div, you have to work with `<script> </script>` tags and address that particular div. Otherwise just add another .js file on the head of the HTML file to make it do something on that div.

Answer (score 0):

Hy

You can get a reference of that DIV, with `var dvo = document.getElementById('id_div');`

Then you can do and apply what you want to only that div.